# Is there an elegant way to pass multiple functions with different amount of parameters into another function in python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, contextmanager

This block of code looks insanely similar and I'm looking for a way to create one function from the both of them:

```
guardians = ["guardianPogchamp", "guardianKappa", "guardianKappaPride", "guardianSmorc", "guardianTrihard"]

with pocofixtures.poco.freeze() as frozen_poco:
    for guardian in guardians:
        if guardian == 'guardianLul':
            assert_text_equal(frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("countdown"),"Immune")
        else:
            assert_text_match(frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("countdown"),"Not Immune")

with pocofixtures.poco.freeze() as frozen_poco:
    for guardian in guardians:
        if guardian == 'guardianLul':
            assert_visible(frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("PetContainer"))
        else:
            assert_not_visible(frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("PetContainer"))
```

This is one of the solutions I tried:

```
def custom_assert(func1, func1Args, func2, func2Args):
    guardians = ["guardianPogchamp", "guardianKappa", "guardianKappaPride", "guardianSmorc", "guardianTrihard"]

    with pocofixtures.poco.freeze() as frozen_poco:
        for guardian in guardians:
            if guardian == 'guardianLul':
                func1(*func1Args)
            else:
                func2(*func2Args)

custom_assert(assert_text_equal, (frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("countdown"), "Immune") , assert_text_match, (frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("countdown"),"Not Immune"))
custom_assert(assert_visible, frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("PetContainer"), assert_not_visible, frozen_poco(guardian).offspring("PetContainer"))
```

But the variables frozen_poco and guardian are only defined inside the function and not when it is called so the code doesn't run. I also tried unpacking and repacking the the variables inside the function but it slows down the runtime a lot. I know there should be an elegant solution to this but i don't know what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback functions can take frozen_poco and guardian, or frozen_poco(guardian) as args:

```
custom_assert(
    lambda fp, g: assert_text_equal(fp(g).offspring("countdown"), "Immune") ,
    lambda fp, g: assert_text_match(fp(g).offspring("countdown"),"Not Immune"))
```

And called like:

```
func1(frozen_poco, guardian)
func2(frozen_poco, guardian)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work like that, although that will mean less flexibility (as the frozen_poco-stuff will always be the first argument, but for your example this is enough).

```
def custom_assert(func1, pocoarg1, func1Args, func2, pocoarg2, func2Args):
    guardians = ["guardianPogchamp", "guardianKappa", "guardianKappaPride", "guardianSmorc", "guardianTrihard"]
    with pocofixtures.poco.freeze() as frozen_poco:
        for guardian in guardians:
            if guardian == 'guardianLul':
                func1(frozen_poco(guardian).offspring(pocoarg1), *func1Args)
            else:
                func2(frozen_poco(guardian).offspring(pocoarg2), *func2Args)

custom_assert(assert_text_equal, "countdown", ["Immune"], assert_text_match, "countdown",["Not Immune"])

custom_assert(assert_visible, "PetContainer", [], assert_not_visible, "PetContainer", [])
```